# MSN XMPP API fails to connect

Tags: api, xmpp, msn

I'm trying to use MSN XMPP API via Actionscript, but connection to MSN always fails. I can identify this error on logs:

```
I DONT KNOW HOW TO HANDLE DER stuff of TYPE 22
I DONT KNOW HOW TO HANDLE DER stuff of TYPE 12
I DONT KNOW HOW TO HANDLE DER stuff of TYPE 22
I DONT KNOW HOW TO HANDLE DER stuff of TYPE 22
(..)
> <stream:error
> xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><see-other-host
> xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams">BY2MSG4020608.gateway.edge.messenger.live.com</see-other-host></stream:error> </stream:stream>
```

Anyone knows what is this related to?

Comment: You don't say what library you use, or anything about the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

The stream error [see-other-host is defined in RFC 6120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-4.9.3.19) as a kind of redirect.  It means that the server wants you to retry connecting to another host.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft introduced changes with their latest server update in April. See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826554.aspx

So after TLS negotiation they always send this stream error and close the stream. You have to open a new XMPP stream to the host given in the see-other-host error. This is their way of XMPP load balancing :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the stream error and get those kind of URL "BY2MSG4020608.gateway.edge.messenger.live.com"
Maybe you have to access to the raw response.
We could help you (code examples) if you provide some information about the library you are using.